# Select the first group in a expandableListView

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

I'm making an app for my Android TV stick. The remote control followed with the package is not so sufficient as regular smartphones touch function. So I'm forced to avoid any mouse/fingers movement as possible.

This is the problem I'm facing:

I made a **Navigation drawer** containing a **Expandable listView**. Everything works as it should. It opens and closes very smoothly. Since I'm not gonna use my fingers or any mouse pointer, one of the **items** in the **expandable listview** needs to be **selected** when I **open** the drawer.

The Expandable listView is made with a **custom group** and **custom child layout.**
What I've done so far, beside googling the S***t out of me is following:

**In the Main activity where the Ex-listview is located:**

```
            <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:groupIndicator="@null"
            />
```

**The custom-group.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="48dp"
          android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/left_row_final"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/group_indicator"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**And the list_item_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#2a669d"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FAFAFA"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**And finally in Activity-main.Java I have following**

```
  private void Initiate() {
    // Defining Drawer Layout
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // Adding Channels
    prepareListData();
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
    Log.e("TAG", "THE LISTVIEW CREATED");
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            expListView.setItemChecked(0,true); // Even tried Itemselected(position) No result. Tried also requestFocus and edited the list-Item-selector.xml for both cases(selected, focused,checked). tried even Itemcanfocus



            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    });
}
```

What I want is : when you open the navigationdrawer the first item in the picture should get selected so you only need to click on it and open the dropdown. 'Kurdish' group in the pictures should get highlighted and ready for user's command to open. Imagine that you control your devide from a remote control. you don't want to use mouse so much. only some buttons like 'OK'. this is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Kurdish row background need to get highlighted to some other color and ready for clicking]

I followed many of answers and questions here still no solution. I hope somebody can help me with this.

Thanks in advance
// Peyam

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExpandableListView.setSelectedChild()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setSelectedChild(int,%20int,%20boolean)) or [ExpandableListView.setSelectedGroup()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setSelectedGroup(int)).

Comment: Hi again, I can't see any differences